# Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected on a different folder

Tags: c#, .net

So I get this error:

> "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected" and "Identifier { expected"

while declaring a file in a different folder but in the same namespace and there is no weird curly braces (when I checked).

My code look like this:

```
namespace TubesStimaVisual.try
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

and this is my folder structure:

[image: The error is on class 1]

(The error is on class 1)

Answer (score 0):

`try` is a reserved word, you can't use it as namespace name.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use try elsewhere, it has special meaning to compiler as it's a reserved keyword.

For reserved keywords, refer this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/